# Unable to add column using ALTER

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-server-2008

I'm creating a table using the following code

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[t_emp](
[empid] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
[salary] [numeric](10, 2) NOT NULL,
[dept] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL)
```

And also i'm trying to add column using the following code,

**`alter table t_emp  add column ename varchar(50) not null`**

But i'm getting the following error,

```
Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 2
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'column'.
```

Please guide me the correct way to achieve my objective.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use Command without `Column`

```
Aَlter Table t_emp Add ename varchar(50) not null
```